# Lscape (or better: pdflscape) package doesn't fill my page properly

Tags: pdflscape, lscape

Can you see a weird behaviour on the second page?

The `lipsum` text contained within it won't fill the page properly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
     \pagestyle{empty}
     \section{Introduction}
      \lipsum[1-7]
      \newpage
            \begin{landscape}
                  \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
                  \lipsum[4-6]
            \end{landscape}
      \newpage
      \section{Body}
      \lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any suggestions please?

Comment: why would you expect ` \newgeometry` to work in `landcape`? certainly that's never been tested, or documented as working

Comment: you might possibly do better to change the geometry first before landscape, and restore after

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to do this because I need to fit a big tabular in a single page

Comment: Great, changing the geometry before landscape and restoring it after worked perfectly!

Comment: you should not use newgeometry unless you need a different page size, eg an A3 insert in an A4 document, don't use it just to adjust the margins.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am posting this as an alternative, it doesn't use `pdflscape` but I use it in my documents so it might be helpful to either you or future readers. I added `margin=2cm` to your `geometry` options just so options could be set in `\paperAFourPortrait`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea} %------------------- <<<< added:  load before geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2cm]{geometry}

% Page sizes
\newcommand\paperAFourLandscape{%
    \cleardoublepage%
    \KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=landscape,DIV=last}%
    \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}%
}

\newcommand\paperAFourPortrait{%
    \clearpage%
    \KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=portrait,pagesize}%
    \recalctypearea%
    \newgeometry{margin=2cm}
}

\begin{document}
     \pagestyle{empty}
     \section{Introduction}
      \lipsum[1-7]
      \newpage
      \paperAFourLandscape
      \lipsum[1-4]
      \paperAFourPortrait
      \newpage
      \section{Body}
      \lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who helped me: it worked perfectly this way

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
     \pagestyle{empty}
     \section{Introduction}
      \lipsum[1-7]
      \newpage
             \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
            \begin{landscape}
                  \lipsum[4-6]
            \end{landscape}
      \restoregeometry
      \newpage
      \section{Body}
      \lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

That is, changing the geometry of the landscape page before rotating and restoring it after, even though the boxes don't match.

No warnings, no badboxes

[image]